# Getting DOMDocument data outside of a foreach

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

I have a small problem here that no amount of searching has been able to resolve as of yet. I am making a script that pulls data from a diagnostic tool, using cURL. I can explain more about how this works, but the issue is just a matter of syntax and not knowing what I need. Here's my code:

```
    $dom = new domdocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($curlhtml);
    $finder = new DomXPath($dom);
    $headname="msg_head";
    $statname="msg_sub_head";
    $headnodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $headname ')]");     
    foreach ($headnodes as $head) 
    {
        $header = $head->nodeValue;
        $headarray[] = $head->nodeValue;

        $statnodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $statname ')]");

        ${$header}[] = $statnodes->nodevalue;
    }
```

My goal is to load all the results from the "statnodes" query into separate arrays, named after all the results in the "headnodes" query.

$head->nodeValue grabs exactly what I want, as it should, since $head is declared in the foreach loop. However, $statnodes->nodeValue does not. I'm aware it *shouldn't* work that way, but I don't know which way I could accomplish this.

I would appreciate any feedback, and I'll be glad to provide responses and edits as needed for any clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DOMXPath::query` returns a [`DOMNodeList`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) so you can also access the elements via [`DOMNodelist::item`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnodelist.item.php). Asumming you are only after the first value in the query result you can do `${$header}[] = $statnodes->item(0)->nodevalue;` or loop through it if you want all the values.

```
foreach ($statnodes as $stat) 
{
   ${$header}[] = $stat->nodevalue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Sadly, no, I'm looking to load every result from the query into the ${$header}[] array.

Comment: @Jon then you'll have to do it in a loop.

Comment: I was starting to think as much. Would it be terrible if I asked for an example, so I could be pointed in the right direction?

Comment: Thanks for the help. This pointed me in the right direction and lead to a resolution. :)